# a function that removes a character from string

Tags: javascript, loops

I want a function to remove a character form a strig

```
function remove(str, charToRmv){}
```

i know how to use `replace` `split` `join`

```
var a = "This*Is*A*String"
console.log(a.replace(/\*/g, ""));

var a = "This*Is*A*String"
console.log(a.split(/\*/g).join(''));

var a = "strinASrting"
console.log(a.replace(/A/g, ""));

var a = "strinASrting"
console.log(a.split('A').join(''));
```

**But I want it to use loop to remove that character**

```
function remove(str, rmv){

      }
```

I expect the output of `("This*Is*A*String", "*")` to be `'ThisIsAString'`

and

I expect the output of `("strinASrting", "A")` to be `'strinString'`

Comment: `str.lenght` will not work. Also `don't know how to code here` Please post what you've tried for the `for` loop body that isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over each character of the string and don't include the given char, like this:

```js
let remove_char = function(str, ch) {
  let newString = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== ch)
      newString += str[i];
  }
  return newString;
}
```

Another implementation, with `replace`:

```js
let remove_char = function(str, ch) {
  while (str.indexOf(ch) >= 0)
    str = str.replace(ch, "")
  return str;
}
alert(remove_char("THIS*IS*ME", "*"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.   and also if I want to put the result in substrings after removing that char what should i do?? like if I want the result of  `("This*Is*A*String", "*")` to be `(["This","Is","A","String"])`

Comment: @NewUser if this is what you want so I think you should `split` instead of `remove`, moreover, you could implement `remove` with `replace`

Comment: in that case it only removes the first char that it recognizes like out pu of `('t*e*s*t', '*')` will be `"te*s*t"`